# How to change events in pygame based on neural network predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, pygame

For the past week, I have been making a neural network to play the popular game Pong. I've made the neural network with keras and though it works and runs, I have no idea how to set it up to actually play the Pong game that was made in Pygame.

Here is the relevant code:

```
model = load_model('first_model_simplify_16.h5')

#scaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))

#mean scaler
def normalize(a):
    mean = np.mean(a)
    stddev = np.std(a)
    sA = [(x-mean)/stddev for x in a]
    return sA

# game loop
while True:

    draw(window)
    #loop that inserts the paddle and ball position in their place in the list

# create array to save all the features
a = np.array([ball_pos[0], ball_pos[1], paddle1_pos[1]])
sA = np.array(normalize(a)).reshape(1,-1)

prediction = model.predict_classes(sA)
print(prediction)

for event in pygame.event.get():

    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        keydown(event)

        if event.key == K_w :
            X.append([ball_pos[0], ball_pos[1], paddle1_pos[1], ball_pos[1] - paddle1_pos[1]])

        elif event.key == K_s :
            X.append([ball_pos[0], ball_pos[1], paddle1_pos[1], ball_pos[1] - paddle1_pos[1]])

    elif event.type == KEYUP:
        keyup(event)
    elif event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
#TESTING


pygame.display.update()
fps.tick(60)
```

The model is making prediction (albeit not very good ones) but I have no idea how to use those prediction to move either paddle up or down.

How can I change an event in pygame using my model's predictions?

EDIT: This is the output for the model

```
C:\Users\berro\Anaconda3.6\python.exe 
C:/Users/berro/PycharmProjects/SecondPongGame/testPong.py
C:\Users\berro\Anaconda3.6\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py:36: 
FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` 
to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 
== np.dtype(float).type`.
from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Using TensorFlow backend.
2018-07-14 13:17:54.652176: I 
T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] 
Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled 
to use: AVX2
[1]
[1]
[1]
[1]
[1]
[1]
```

and it continues to output every single frame. 
Also it is sometimes a 0 depending on the input.

Comment: What is the output of print(prediction)?

Comment: @causation I edited the question to include that output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how keras works, but if you want to add events to pygame's event queue if a  condition is true, you can use the [`pygame.event.post`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.post) function.

First of all you have to create a [`pygame.event.Event`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Event) instance which will be passed to `pygame.event.post`. You need to pass an event type as the first argument, for example `pygame.KEYDOWN` or `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`, and a dictionary or keyword args which define the specific values of the event like the `key`, `unicode` and `scancode` attributes. (`MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` and `MOUSEBUTTONUP` events only have a `pos` and a `button` attribute.)

Here's an example in which a `pygame.KEYDOWN` event is added to the queue every 60 frames.

```
import pygame


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
BG_COLOR = pygame.Color('gray12')
frame_count = 0

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            print(event)
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                print('w key pressed')

    frame_count += 1

    if frame_count >= 60:
        frame_count = 0
        # Either pass a dictionary ...
        # event = pygame.event.Event(pygame.KEYDOWN, {'key': pygame.K_w, 'unicode': 'w', etc.})
        # or pass keyword arguments.
        event = pygame.event.Event(pygame.KEYDOWN, key=pygame.K_w, unicode='w', scancode=17, mod=0)
        # Add the event to pygame's event queue.
        pygame.event.post(event)

    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

---

Edit: Since you just want to move the paddle up or down depending on the prediction value, you could simply set the speed of the paddle to a corresponding value:

```
if prediction == [0]:
    paddle_speed = -5
elif prediction == [1]:
    paddle_speed = 5

paddle_pos_y += paddle_speed
```

Comment: Hmm, will this allow me to add an event every frame depending on whether the output is a "0" or a "1"? So, if the output is 0, the paddle moves down, and if the output is "1" the paddle moves up.

Comment: Yes, this will add an event to the queue every frame if the condition is true. If the paddle should move up if the output is 0 and down if it's 1, you could simply set the speed of the paddle to a corresponding value, e.g.: `if output == 0: speed_y = -5`. So you wouldn't have to mess around with the event queue.

Comment: Ok thank you. It now works and I didn't need to "post" an event.